# How to use overlay mask on any page using css and javascript only

Tags: javascript, css

I tried different types of masks. I need to be able to dynamically create css class and add it after DOM was loaded to achieve overlay mask.
I tried :

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.overlay-loader-mobile-edition { height: 100%; width: 
100%; position: fixed !important; z-index: 5000000 !important;left: 0 
!important;background-color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: 
rgba(0,0,0,0.9);overflow-x:hidden;transition: 0.5s;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
document.body.className = 'overlay-loader-mobile-edition';
```

With no luck.
For instance on google if I type this command in console I get those results:

[image]

I was following W3 example :
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_overlay

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are adding the class to the `body` making the `body` element to be the overlay which is not the correct way to do. Instead use a pseudo element that will be your overlay element and will cover everything inside the `body`:

```js
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.overlay-loader-mobile-edition:before {content:"";height: 100%; width: 100%; position: fixed !important; z-index: 5000000 !important;left: 0 !important;background-color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);overflow-x:hidden;transition: 0.5s;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
document.body.className = 'overlay-loader-mobile-edition';
```

Comment: Thanks for heads up. Updated version works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution that works on every website, unless some element will have higher z-index.

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = '.overlay-loader-mobile-edition:before {content:"";height: 100%; 
width: 100%; position: fixed !important; z-index: 5000000 !important;left: 0 
!important; top:0 !important;background-color: rgb(0,0,0);background-color: 
rgba(0,0,0,0.3);overflow-x:hidden;transition: 0.5s;}';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
var divElement = document.createElement("div");
divElement.setAttribute("id", "overlay-mobile-mask-div");
divElement.className = "overlay-loader-mobile-edition";
document.body.appendChild(divElement)
```

Thank you Temani for pointing out that brand new element should have been created.

Comment: no need to create a new element, this is the main purpose of pseudo element, it's already an element ... creating another is simply redundant.